# Android : close all the activities when Login activity is started

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activity Login and Main, when the user start the application, the Main activity start and verify if the user is login, if not, the app redirect the user to the login activity.
All that works fine, but the problem when the Back Button click in login activity the app start the activity Main, I want the app exit.. 
Any help please.

Comment: call finish() when you are redirecting it to login activity...

Comment: use flags i.e, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: these flags clear the stack

Comment: I used flags, and I added condition when app redirect user to login activity I added finish() method to destroy the main activity. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
                Intent i = new Intent(First_screen.this, Second_screen.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
```

when you go to `second_screen`.. it will clear all the other activities before that..

Comment: Are these flags needed for compatibility? I just added the finish method and it is working.

Answer (score 2):

You can add android:noHistory="true" to AndroidManifest.xml when declaring your Activity, this is one way of doing it.

Example:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:noHistory="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check instance of your main activity before moving to login activity
 Make sure that there is not active activity before you intent to login activity of you are not sure you can define a instance on that activity

On mainactivity.class

public static MainActivity maininstance=MainActivity.this;

On my login activity back press

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    if(MainActivity.mainInstance!=null)
    {
        MainActivity.mainInstance.finish();
    }
    LoginActivity.this.finish();

}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

It works for me adding

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```